# Unity vuforia error get projection matrix in the newer version

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am getting error CS0117: `Vuforia.VuforiaUnity' does not contain a definition for`GetProjectionGL'.

This function is depreciated. Can anybody tell me whats the replacement function ?

Comment: From what I can find online it was removed from the SDK